# Is this anecdote about the adoption of best practices true?

Tags: history, programming-productivity

I've been forwarded this by a colleague:

> There’s a great story of a manager of a Coca-cola plant who’s numbers were far better than his peers. When asked what his “secret” was, he said simply that rather than take a best practice and modify it to meet what the plant did, he instead modified the plant to match the best practice. His secret was not trying to be too clever.

—[Object Mentor blog](http://web.archive.org/web/20121017105658/http://blog.objectmentor.com/articles/2011/05/24/bamboo-reminds-me-of-a-time-when)

Is this something which really happened, or just some made-up example?

Comment: @Larian LeQuella Why add the "quotes"?

Comment: @Dave Hillier The quotes separate the thing being asked about.  When I first read it, it was I had a great deal of trouble parsing what the question was.  This way it clarifies that the anecdote is about the adoption of best practices, not a best practice of adoption.

Comment: I don't understand what the quote means? What is "applying best practice" if not modifying the plant the match it? Is the story that the first guy wrote what the plant was doing and called it best practice?

Comment: @DJClayworth it's a story about *how* best practices are adopted.